# No items appear in UITableView

Tags: ios

I have a simple application with UITableView
no items appear even though they should. What do i forget...
(I know cellForRowAtIndexPath is called)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [[cell textLabel] setText:@"terlala"];
    return cell;
}
```

Table view controller is invoked using

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     // Override point for customization after application launch.
     self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     SillyTableViewController * CamerasViewController = [[SillyTableViewController alloc] init];
    [[self window] addSubview:[CamerasViewController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
 }
```

Comment: You're saying that `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is being called, but no cell shows up?

Comment: have u binded UITableView's delegate and dataSource?

Comment: Carl : yes. I see in the debugger that it's called.
Prince : YES. both are connected to File owner. 
I have created very small example that demonstrate it. I know I forget something... AHHHHH

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your nib or your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
         [super viewDidLoad];
    }

Comment: Carl : I put very small example that demonstrate it under dev.scipio.org/SillyTable.zip

Comment: That example works just fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/w6lEw.png

Comment: Instead of `[[self window] addSubview:[CamerasViewController view]];` use `[[self window] setRootViewController:CamerasViewController];` Otherwise nothing is stopping ARC reclaim your view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the identifier "Cell" is in your cell attribute inspector